# Preparing Data for Convolutional Neural Network Training

Tags: r, dataset, heatmap

I am working on a project that involves creating a set of *n* heat maps that will become the training data for a CNN to perform a binary classification. As of now, I have 1,000 heat maps with 649 in the majority class and 351 in the minority class (I can make more heat maps if needed). My question is this: how are images prepped for CNN training? Are all of the images compiled into one data set? If so, any ideas on how to accomplish this in R?

I'm going for conceptual understanding here. I understand what the CNN does I'm just not sure how to set-up the training data. Any guidance is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just reshape each heatmap's grid element values into a single vector, and use each vector as an object for the classification run.  This is no different than what is commonly done for image classification, where gray-scale values of RGB for e.g. $100 \times 100$ bitmap pixel images are reshaped into $1 \times 10000$ vectors for classification analysis.  After you line up the $n$ vectors and the e.g. 10000 columns (features) you can run PCA to collapse the 10000 dimensions down to $1 \times 10$ for each object.  As you can see, there is an unlimited amount of transformations that can be applied to the heat map data elements, especially, how to collapse the dimensions.  PCA will help in noise reduction as well as removing redundancy.  These are quite antiquated approaches, but the intent is to show what can be done to get started.

Comment: Great! So the preparing the data for CNNs is exactly the same as ANNs? Thanks for the help!